# No route matches for delete form when I set url. Other solutions, cause other problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

I have a self-referential join relationship between users using a friendship join table which looks like:

user > friendship > user (renamed friends)

In my index page I want to have a button containing two hidden forms for create and destroy next to each user to friend or unfriend depending on the state of the relationship. I have the create relationship working fine, but for the destroy I'm having a few problems. Right now I'm working with 4 possibilities, each of which have their own problems.

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.friend-button").on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-friended friend-button');
        $(this).find("form.friend-form:hidden").submit();
    });

    $("li.button-friended").on('click', function(event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('button-friended friend-button');
        $(this).find("form.unfriend:hidden").submit();
    });
});
```

The ERB

```
<li class="<%= friended ? "button-friended" : "friend-button" %>">Friend
<!-- From UsersController: @friendship = Friendship.new -->
<%= form_for [user, @friendship], :remote => true, html: { :class => 'friend-form'}  do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %> #This creates fine
<% end %>
```

Option 1:

```
<% friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(user.id)%>
<%= form_for friendship, :method => :delete, :remote => true, html: {class: "unfriend"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %> # Works as long as all users are friended, otherwise has error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class. Since the friendship is nil.
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def destroy
@friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
@friendship.destroy
```

Option 2

```
<%= form_for user, :method => :delete, :url => friendship_path, :remote => true, html: {class: "unfriend"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %> # Error: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"friendships"}. Since it's form_for user, but heading to the FrendshipsController (I guess)
<% end %>
```

And yes I already saw this: A long-standing bug prevents form_for from working automatically with singular resources. As a workaround, specify the URL for the form directly, like so:
form_for @geocoder, url: geocoder_path do |f|

from  edgeguides

Controller

```
def destroy
@friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(params[:id])
@friendship.destroy
```

Option 3

```
<%= form_for [user, @friendship], :url => user_friendship_path, :remote => true, html: {class: "unfriend"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %> #Also: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"friendships"}, but no idea why
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def destroy
@friendship = current_user.friendships.find_by_friend_id(params[:user_id])
@friendship.destroy
```

Option 4

```
<%= form_for [user, @friendship], :method => :delete, :remote => true, html: {class: "unfriend"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %> #Page finally renders, but get this from the dev.log:

Started DELETE "/users/4/friendships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-19 13:56:01 -0400
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/4/friendships"):
```

Controller same as O3

Relevant routes:

```
user_friendships POST   /users/:user_id/friendships(.:format) friendships#create
user_friendship DELETE /users/:user_id/friendships/:id(.:format) friendships#destroy
friendship DELETE /friendships/:id(.:format)            friendships#destroy
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having a similar problem (although it doesn't seem like many of you based on the research I did).

So, the best I could come up with is a pretty bad hack, but it gets the job done. On the command line I created a "fake friendship"

```
 => #<Friendship id: 51, created_at: "2013-07-20 13:04:28", updated_at: "2013-07-20 13:04:28", user_id: 0, friend_id: 0>
```

Although, it doesn't have to be fake, I just wanted something with an `id` to solve this:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/8/friendships")

Which I got from option 4 from above.

So, here's the code:

UsersController:

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    @friendship = Friendship.new
    @friends = current_user.friends.order('id')
    # gives me a "friendship" to enter into friendship delete forms so it routes
    # properly, never changes since the delete controller only worries about
    # the user_id
    @fake_friendship = Friendship.find(51)
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [user, @fake_friendship], :method => :delete, :remote => true, html: {class: "unfriend"} do |f| %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `redirect_to friendship_path, status: 303` after `@friendship.destroy`

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some >browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable >behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303. See Other status code >which will be followed using a GET request.

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to